# ip addr show is showing me two IP address on one interface

Tags: networking, ip

I am seeing two IP address on a single interface in a weird way.
This is my output of **ifconfig -a**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:26:b1:c8  
          inet addr:10.0.0.22  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:519 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:63643 (62.1 KiB)  TX bytes:111910 (109.2 KiB)
```

This is my **/etc/network/interfaces** file output

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.22
        subnet  255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.0.0.1

auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
#       address 0
#       subnet  255.255.255.0
#       gateway 192.168.0.2
```

And this is my output for **sudo ip addr show**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:26:b1:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.22/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.100/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ovs-system state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:6c:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.78.64/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As we can see here **eth0** has two ip address and is only shown by ip command and not by ifconfig or /etc/network/interfaces file. I am unable to understand from where this is coming or how to disable the 2nd IP permanently. I would like to get rid of the 2nd IP address permanently.

I have also noticed that this IP comes after a second or so when the system is booted. When I do dmesg I see these are the last few lines-

```
[   15.270464] device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
[   15.576206] asix 1-1.4:1.0 eth1: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
```

Comment: What's the question here?  It is entirely possible to have multiple IP addresses assigned to the same device.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the other IP address permanently (even after reboots).

Comment: Make sure that you don't use `auto` and `allow-hotplug` together - one or the other will work (start with that).  See if on reboot it still gets two addresses.

Comment: I tried removing "auto" and "allow-hotplug" lines individually and both at the same time and rebooted but I still get the same result.

Comment: It seems that subnet setting of your `interfaces` is not respected either. Maybe you should call it  `netmask`

Comment: After changing `subnet` to `netmask` i can see `inet 10.0.0.22/24`. But still there are 2 IPs there.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.

Finally found that in my distro (debian jessie) the static ip is set in the file **/etc/dhcpcd.conf** and looked like:

```
 ...
 39 # A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
 40 # server, but it should not be run by default.
 41 nohook lookup-hostname
 42 ## interface eth0
 43   static ip_address=192.168.1.2/24
 44   static routers=192.168.1.254
 45   static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.254
 46 ## interface eth0
 47   static ip_address=192.168.0.3/24
 48   static routers=192.168.0.1
 49   static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

So I've removed that additional record from that file and it fixed that issue permanently.

Hope it will help someone...

Answer (score 2):

Old thread I know but,

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:26:b1:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    **inet 10.0.0.22/8** brd 10.255.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

    **inet 10.0.0.100/24** brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The request was "How do I get rid of the "10.0.0.100/24" address

This will get rid of it

```
ip address del 10.0.0.100/24 dev eth0
```

This will put it back

```
ip address add 10.0.0.100/24 dev eth0
```

These are both "non-persistent" so a better question might be what keeps putting that address on your interface

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.

After trying to set a static IP in my `/etc/netplan/99-config.yaml` and still not being able to get a network connection (as well as seeing two IP addresses with `ip a`). I dug around and read that dhcpd could be a possible cause.

`cat /etc/dhcpd.conf`

Produced:

```
...
# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private
interface enp3s0
        static ip_address=192.168.0.15/24
        static routers=192.168.0.1
        static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

Where I could see that for some reason I had set a static IP in `/etc/dhcpd.conf`.

So I removed those lines and I finally was able to establish a network connection, and `ip a` showing just the single the static IP I had set in `/etc/netplan/99-config.yaml`.

Answer (score -4):

A `whois` query on that IP address shows:

```
WHOIS results for 169.254.78.64
NetRange:       169.254.0.0 - 169.254.255.255
CIDR:           169.254.0.0/16
NetName:        LINKLOCAL-RFC3927-IANA-RESERVED
NetHandle:      NET-169-254-0-0-1
Parent:         NET169 (NET-169-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        IANA Special Use
OriginAS:
Organization:   Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)
RegDate:        1998-01-27
Updated:        2014-01-09
Comment:        Computers use addresses starting with "169.254." when they do not have a manually configured address or when they are not told which address to use by a service on the network.  They are commonly called the "link local" addresses.
Comment:
Comment:        Routers are not allowed to forward packets sent from an IPv4 "link local" address, so they are always used by a directly connected device.
Comment:
Comment:        These addresses were assigned by the IETF, the organization that develops Internet protocols, in the Standards Track document, RFC3927, which can be found at:
Comment:        http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3927
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-169-254-0-0-1
```

so it's not a big problem. The interface is `promiscuous`, which means it will receive ALL packets.

To see which processes have it open, `man lsof`, `sudo lsof /dev/eth1` will help.

Comment: that's `eth1` and not the focus of the OP's question.  OP wants to remove one of the two IP addresses on ***`eth0`***, not `eth1`

Comment: Well, I don't care about this IP for eth1. My concern is for eth0 which has two IP address and the rogue IP I want to get rid of permanently is 10.0.0.100/24